# Comparing fitting methods for the same model. Bland-Altman and Mann-Whitney

Tags: goodness-of-fit, fitting, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, bland-altman-plot

I have fit my experimental data (about 50 analysis) to the same model using two diferente methods. 
The model is of the type: $ y = A + B * (x^C) $.

I obtained my results as two tables with the columns A, B, C, RSS, chi2 for each one.

Now I wanna compare the results to see if there is agrément between the methods, i.e., if the parameter A (the most importante for me) is similar in both methods and if the chi2 results (which I'm using to check the goodnedd of fit is ok) are similar as well.

I thought about making a Bland-Altman plot for the parameter A in order to check its measurements in both methods and see if they agree or not.

Then, Mann-Whitney test for my chi2's and see if they behave the same.

I have density plots of them and they behave quite the same.

Does it sound any good ? It's not for a paper. I'm just trying to change a lab procedure.

Comment: If you have two algorithms for estimating the parameters, and both are guaranteed to converge, and your problem is convex (i.e., has only one minimum), they should both give the same answer, give or take a tiny amount due to stopping criteria, roundoff errors, etc.  Why do you think you might get very different results?

Comment: Because they do not follow the same algorithm. The first method is actually the equipment software which uses non-linear regression. 
The second one is a modified method available in recente literature. Combining a first estimation for A followed by the estimetion of B and C.

Due to problems with this first method (negative A values) plenty of research has been made to develop new methods to estimate this. The best one is actually the experimental one for A followed by optimization for the others. However, this is expensive and most labs can't afford ...

Comment: By the way, they do not get very diferente results. Instead, they look very similar when I plot against each other. 

However, a stats method would look nicer in the final presentation to my advisor than just showing my plots

Comment: If the only problem is negative values for $A$, that could be easily fixed by estimating $y = \exp(A^*) + Bx^C$ instead; the old $A = \exp(A^*)$ and is guaranteed to be positive.  Simultaneous estimation of the parameters will work better than sequential estimation almost always...

Comment: Thank you for this tip. I never really thought of doing this way.Instead, I tried to just force A > 0 and see what would come. But that's not the only problem, just the most significant one. B and C are also problematic sometimes and do not show any chemical meaningful result. That's why we have been trying to combine the experimental interpretation in the problem solving whole thing. If I keep the method the way I did, is that ok to have a simple comparison the way I planned ? Bland-Altman for A and then Mann-Whitney for chi2 ?